# Project uses CodeSmith to generate the database but I don't have Codesmith anymore

Tags: codesmith

I am new to Codesmith gen so...

I don't have CodeSmith anymore, but my project uses CodeSmith to generate all the database context. I want to add a table to the database. Is there anyway possible to have the code generated for that table also, even though I don't have CodeSmith anymore ?

How can I still work with the new table ?

thanks guys...

Answer (score 0):

You would manually have to add the code by hand or install CodeSmith Generator and regenerate. Also, is there a reason you are not using Generator any more?